# Associate macro to forms in an Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Could anyone give me a tip on this problem?

I have added these two "Rounded Rectangle" (B1 and B2) in my worksheet.

[image: Rectangles in the WorkSheet]

I also have written the macro (mainMacro) below:

```
Sub mainMacro() 

if "B1 was selected" then
  'do something
elseif "B2 was selected" then
   'do other thing.
end If 

End Sub
```

My question is: Is there any way to write a VBA code who will do something based on what retangle a user has clicked (as I wrote in the 'If' statement of the mainMacro)?

Obs:I have noted that VBA identifies these rectangles as  :**Array("Rounded Rectangle x")**

Comment: `If ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name = ....`

Comment: To base it on the location instead of the name: `If ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address = ....`

Comment: To base it on the text shown in the shape: `If ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ....`

Comment: @tigeravatar - Ah, right. I misread the question.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of doing what you want to do is to have a form control button instead of a shape.

If you open the developer tab, click insert and under form controls, put a button. In the button macro, you can add the code you want, so if that button is pressed, it will execute that macro.

Then you can add the second code (currently under elseif in your code) to the second form control button.